# Cannot call plugin Controllers in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a plugin named as PanelAdmin. It has Controller `UsersController.php` and inside it there are different actions defined.
I have called the default controller within the plugin through this code

```
$routes->connect('/PanelAdmin', ['plugin' => 'PanelAdmin','controller' => 'default','action' => 'index']);
```

but cannot call other controller if i hit this url:

```
http://localhost/multi_shopping/PanelAdmin/Users/
```

One thing more i want to clear is i have to define routes for all controllers actions in routes.php. Please solve my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your plugin `routes.php` make sure you are setting a fallback route.

**routes.php**

```
<?php
use Cake\Routing\Route\DashedRoute;
use Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder;
use Cake\Routing\Router;

Router::plugin(
    'PanelAdmin',
    ['path' => '/PanelAdmin'],
    function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
        $routes->fallbacks(DashedRoute::class);
    }
);
```

From the DashedRoute class:

```
/**
 * This route class will transparently inflect the controller, action and plugin
 * routing parameters, so that requesting `/my-plugin/my-controller/my-action`
 * is parsed as `['plugin' => 'MyPlugin', 'controller' => 'MyController', 'action' => 'myAction']`
 */
```

Comment: Thanks Mathew- I need to define routes for all controllers action or only for the base controller.

Comment: @user3653474 the `DashedRoute` handler will automatically route controller names to controller functions for `/PanelAdmin/controller/action` routes.